# cakephp - localization not working

Tags: cakephp, localization, cakephp-2.0

I have cakephp 2 with "fre" as the default language but for some odd reason in my form where I have birthday, my months are still in English. Here's my code

```
 echo $this->Form->input('User.birthday', 
        array (
            'label' => array('text'=>__("form_birthday", "true"), 
                      'class' => ''),

            'selected' => 'empty',
            'dateFormat' => 'MDY',
            'minYear' => date('Y') - 90,
            'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18,
            'separator'=> " ",
            'empty' => __('select', true)
        )
    );
```

Anyone know how I can translate the month names to French. My default.po already has the French translation of the months.

Comment: In 2.x the `__()` method returns the translation right away (no true as second param).
It's in the documention and also mentioned in the migration guide in case you upgraded recently from 1.x: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#internationalization-localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the following line in the bootstrap file and it works great.

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra');
```

Answer (score 3):

### CakePHP is PHP

As mentioned in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp):

> There’s one other aspect of localizing your application which is not covered by the use of the translate functions, and that is date/money formats. Don’t forget that CakePHP is PHP :), therefore to set the formats for these things you need to use [setlocale](http://php.net/setlocale).

As such, to localize dates you need to call setlocale somewhere appropriate - such as your `AppController::beforeFilter` if it's a multilingual app - or `app/bootstrap.php` if it's single language.

### Alternatively

If instead of relying on `setlocale` (which is the better idea) you prefer a bit more control you can use the `'monthNames' => true` to use "normal" translations rather than the output of `strfrtime`. You'll find this [in the source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L2572). You can get a French po file from [the localized repository](https://github.com/cakephp/localized/blob/master/Locale/fre/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po) - which in addition to translating month names for you, also translates all the other standard texts that come out of the core.

### If all else fails

You should never land here - but if nothing is working (this *will* mean that there are mistakes in your application) you can just defined `monthNames` to a normal array of month number -> name, and this will take precedence over automatically derived month names.

Comment: I have `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA.utf8');` in my bootstrap.php and I have no luck.

Comment: My setlocale is now `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA');` which when used in a standalone php file does show the french date. Now I changed locale to "fra". Still now luck. Here is my Appcontroller.php http://pastebin.com/k1cJkt9H

Comment: Still having issues after only having `Configure::write('Config.language', "fra");` in my beforeFilter. I also already called parent::beforeFilter in my subclass. All those other codes are proof that I'm in desperate need of a solution.. Everything else (form labels & other text) are translated from Locale/fre/LC_MESSAGES/default.po but my month names are just not being converted to french.

Answer (score 0):

**There are a couple of steps:**

First, set the locale to be used.
Create one or more .po files for that language.
Wrap all of your l10n-able strings with the __() or __d() helper methods.
Here's an excerpt from one of my projects:

```
uses ( 'L10n' );

class AppController extends Controller {
 public function beforeFilter() {
  /**
 * Derive the desired locale by reading the subdomain from
 * the HTTP_HOST server variable. Locale subdomains can use
 * either the 2 or 3 character ISO code. Information on locale
 * ISO codes is at http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php.
 */
$this->L10n = new L10n();

/** Auto-detect the request language settings */
$this->L10n->get();

/**
 * Set the default "domain" for translations. The domain is the
 * same as the po file name in a given locale directory. e.g.
 * __d( 'homepage', 'message_id' ) would look for the
 * message_id key in homepage.po. Using the __() convenience
 * function will always look in default.po.
 */
$this->set( 'domain', 'default' );
}

# The rest of your AppController code
}
```

That snippet will set the language. All you need to do is provide the appropriate .po files in the /app/locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/ directory. The CakePHP book provides sufficient information on this, I think. http://book.cakephp.org/view/161/Internationalization-Localization

If you choose to use just one .po file, you'll wrap your strings with the __() helper. I chose multiple .po files in order to avoid one massive file, so I used the __d() helper so that I could specify which domain (domain == name of the .po file without the .po extension).

**UPDATE**

I should add that you'll need to use the Translate behavior to help you with database content that requires translation.

Comment: It didnt work. I dont need to add a Translate behaviour since I dont have db content that I need to translate. I just need my month names in my form to be its FRench equivalent. Here is my code:`App::uses('L10n','I18n'); class AppController extends Controller {
 public $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form');public function beforeFilter(){
  
  $this->L10n = new L10n();
  $this->L10n->get("fre");
  debug($this->L10n);
  $this->set( 'domain', 'default' );
  
  
debug(Configure::read('Config.language'));

  $this->set('lang', $this->getLanguage());
  debug($this->getLanguage());
}`

Comment: This is way off. If you create a new instance of L10n - any property you change will have no effect because your'e not changing the instance that `__()` et.al. are reading from. `L10n->get` [is called automatically as part of the translate function](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php#L153) and `$this->set( 'domain', 'default' );` does absolutely nothing related to translations - it just defines `$domain` as "default" in the view.

Comment: Although this answer is overly complex, it was actually the only answer I've seen where something is making actual use of `L10n`.